# Can't run phpseclib - Branch 2.0

Tags: php, phpseclib

I've followed [this](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) guide (along with the Composer Download instructions) to download and try to install the composer but I get the following on the terminal:

[image: Click here for screenshot of errors in terminal]

Does anyone know what could be causing the issue? I was using branch 1.0 initially but when I put it on my lamp package I had deprecated errors so was apparent that branch 2.0 would fix this issue...?

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1010 has the answers you need?

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here:
https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1010